# HeaderListView with Pull to refresh

Tags: android, listview, header, pull-to-refresh

This Post is Duplicate of :
[PullToRefresh list with pinned section header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17272642/pulltorefresh-list-with-pinned-section-header)
&
[is it possible to merge stickylistviewheader with crisbanes pulltorefresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20143008/is-it-possible-to-merge-stickylistviewheader-with-crisbanes-pulltorefresh)

I need to implement headerListView with pull-to-refresh functionality. I am Googling for possible way to implement it, But still not got any solution.

NOTE: There is a option, Use mergeAdapter to achieve separator, This solution will not work for me, because i need stickyHeader, Not separators.

Thanks,

Comment: -I am facing same problem, did you found your solution?

Comment: @AmritPalSingh : no bro, didn't found any solution yet :(

Comment: Ok bro..if you get some solution to the problem..plz inform me.

Comment: @AmritPalSingh : ok, and if you get any then plz remember to share it with me!

Comment: possible duplicate of [PullToRefresh list with pinned section header](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17272642/pulltorefresh-list-with-pinned-section-header)

Answer (score 1):

[StickyListHeader](https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders) works like a charm with [ActionBar-PullToRefresh](https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh) as long as you use the custom Delegate [as provided here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17272642/pulltorefresh-list-with-pinned-section-header/21124847) by Andrew Emery in the answers; that is :

```
public class StickyListViewDelegate extends AbsListViewDelegate {
    @Override
    public boolean isReadyForPull(View view, final float x, final float y) {
        StickyListHeadersListView sticky = (StickyListHeadersListView) view;
        return super.isReadyForPull(sticky.getWrappedList(), x, y);
    }
}
```

Integrated like so:

```
StickyListViewDelegate delegate = new StickyListViewDelegate();
ActionBarPullToRefresh.from(this).theseChildrenArePullable(mListView)
        .useViewDelegate(StickyListHeadersListView.class, delegate)
        .listener(this).setup(mPullToRefreshLayout);
```

Comment: Link-only answers are generally discouraged as they can't stand on their own long-term. Please quote any relevant information in the answer so as to avoid future problems from link-rot.